# Change style of first row in a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to change the style of the first row in a table, the thing is that it doesn't apply correctly, i need to know if i can change directly the css with the specific tag accessing the first row of a table.

Basicly everytime i check a checkbox it should change the color of the header of my row to blue, and if it is unchecked not.

So i do this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="checkbox-inline control-label col-md-10"><input v-model="hasHeader" type="checkbox">Header Row?</label>
</div>



 <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row,idx1) in tableRows" :class="{headerRowDefault: checkHeader}">
        <td class="table-success" v-for="(col,idx2) in tableCols"><input v-model="table.tableGrid[idx1][idx2]" type="text" class="borderTbl" value="HEY"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**my computed checkHeader method:**

```
checkHeader (idx2) {
      alert('CHECKHEADER')
      if (this.hasHeader === true && idx2 === 0) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
```

is there a way i can on my checkbox trigger the change to the first row, i know i can apply a css style to the first row, but how can i do this on the trigger? any help?

Comment: Computed properties do not take arguments. You need to use a method.

Comment: sorry i confunded i used a method

Comment: how can i use a computed and get that index?

Comment: If `checkHeader` is a method, then try `class="{headerRowDefault: checkHeader(idx1)}"`.

Comment: well that is what i had, it doesn't work

Comment: Directly with CSS you may use the `>` selector like `tbody > tr:first-child { background-color: blue;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like this.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    tableRows:[1,2,3,4,5],
    tableCols: [1,2,3],
    hasHeader: false
  },
  methods:{
    checkHeader (rowIndex) {
      if (this.hasHeader === true && rowIndex === 0) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.headerRowDefault{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="checkbox-inline control-label col-md-10"><input v-model="hasHeader" type="checkbox">Header Row?</label>
  </div>



  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row,idx1) in tableRows" :class="{headerRowDefault: checkHeader(idx1)}">
        <td class="table-success" v-for="(col,idx2) in tableCols">{{idx2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Obviously the example uses fake data. I have no idea what the actual `tableRows` and `tableCols` should be.

Comment: i was dumb enough to forget to do this.table.hasHeader, my issue

Comment: @FilipeCosta We all make dumb mistakes sometimes :)